# Accessing consecutive 250 files using python

Tags: python

In DOS or batch file on windows we can access multiple consecutive files fieldgen1.txt, fieldgen2.txt, etc. as follows:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,250) do (
    copy fieldgen%%i.txt hk.ref
    Process the file and go to next file.
```

I have 250 files name like fieldgen1.ref, fieldgen2.ref, etc. Now I want to access one file, process that file, and access another file whenever processing is done. As I know python do like this

```
with open('fieldgen1.txt', 'r') as inpfile, with open('fieldgen2.txt', 'r') as inpfile:
```

I can access only two files this way. Is there any short way to access multiple consecutive files in python?

Comment: `for n in range(1, 251): with open('fieldgen{}.txt'.format(n), r) as inpfile: ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access and process consecutive files in python

```
for i in range(1, 251):
    with open('fieldgen%s.txt' % i, 'r') as fp:
        lines = fp.readlines()
        # Do all your processing here
```

The code will loop and read each file. You can then do your processing once you have read all the lines. You didn't mention if you needed to alter the file as part of your processing so I am just including the reading part.

If you do need to write back to the file make sure you do that after all the processing is done.

Comment: Thanks Eric Bulloch

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
import os

files = os.listdir(".")

for f in files:
  print (str(f))
```

This will print all files and directories in the current run directory. Once you have the file name you can use that to process the content.

Comment: I think he wants to control the number of files that he needs to display, so your answer is a bit off track.

Answer (score 0):

I will consider using a string template.

```
for i in range(1,251):
    with open('fieldgen'+str(i)+'.txt', 'r') as fp:
        #Parsing your file
```

or you can use a List Comprehension:

```
files = [open('fieldgen'+str(i)+'.txt', 'r') for i in range(1,251)]
for file in files:
    #Parsing your file
```